# lb command couldn't go further after entering the name of the app?

Tags: loopbackjs

```
C:\xxx>lb
? what's the name of your application? yyy
```

loopback cli, lb command bogged down here. After entering the name of the app it couldn't go further. Please someone who faced the same problem help me?

Comment: Had you run the CMD as administrator?

Comment: I've run into the same issue after trying many possible remedies. lb -v 4.2.1. node -v v10.13.0. os: Win 10 Home.